# Outlook 2016 view settings not seen

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Why is it that I dont see the various view settings in my outlook 2016? This is what I see.

[image: view settings in my outlook]

Comment: What are you expecting?

Comment: @Ramhound compact, single, preview. Aren't those the default options?

Comment: I have the exact same options and I am using Outlook 2013 so I would say that, no, it most certainly isn't the default options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that you are using an IMAP account. Compact, Single, Preview are for non-IMAP accounts. Default view settings for an IMAP account are IMAP Messages, Hide Messages Marked for Deletion, Group Messages Marked for Deletion, and Preview, just as it shows in your screenshot.

Comment: gmail is IMAP ? I have linked gmail to my outlook. Is that why it doestn show ?

Comment: Gmail supports both IMAP protocol and POP3 protocol. You may go to File > Account Setting, under the Email tab, check the **Type** column to verify whether your Gmail was set via IMAP in Outlook. As I mentioned before, this is the expected behavior for an IMAP account. Whether linked to Outlook.com doesn't matter.

Answer (score -1):

My Outlook 2016 gives the exact same menu (fresh install).

The three red circles contain the settings that you are trying to change:

[image: The three red circles contain the settings that you are trying to change.]

Comment: The OP comments that "compact, single, preview" is the collection of views apparently missing (only Preview is included).  What you show circled aren't those options.

Comment: @pietdevries : no that's not my question.